R studio: I try to produce a table, it work fine while preview, but when I knit to PDF, it shows itself as latex code

I tried to make a table with R and kableExtra, it looks find in
review but it becomes latex code in pdf, please see the screen
cap of the knitted PDF and my code. it should give a nice table
with the kableExtra function. please see the reproducible code
below. I have another code which is experiencing the same
problem, but I am really not sure what is happening.
popular_names_eight_years <- babynames %>%
  group_by(eight_years = year %/% 8, sex) %>%
  mutate(period = paste0(min(year), '-', max(year)), N = sum(n)) %>%
  group_by(period, sex, name) %>%
  summarize(Total = sum(n), Percent = sum(n) / N[1], .groups = 'drop') %>%
  arrange(period, desc(Total)) %>%
  group_by(period, sex) %>%
  top_n(1, Total) %>%
  ungroup()

caption <- 'Most popular names by every eight years and sex, with totals and percent by sex'

final_table <- popular_names_eight_years %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sex, values_from = c(name, Total, Percent), names_sep = "_")


colnames = c('Period', rep(c('Name', 'Total', 'Percent'), times = 2))


tbl <- final_table %>%
  select(period, contains('_F'), contains('_M')) %>%
  kable(col.names = colnames, booktabs = TRUE, caption = caption, format = "latex") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(position = 'center', full_width = FALSE) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Female" = 3, "Male" = 3))


print(tbl)


Could you edit your question to include reproducible code as text within the question? See here for issues with uploading code as images and why it is discouraged: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? - good luck!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Don't call print(). tbl alone is enough (knitr will call the right print method). You don't even need to create the object tbl (unless you really need to do anything about it later) but just write final_table %>% ... without the assignment.
